# compilation of abstact class type pointer is successfull?

Tags: c++, abstract-class, virtual-functions

Compilation of following code is successful, it doesn't run though, i think since the pointer `p` might be having a `virtual ptr` but that `vptr` might not be having anything, that is why it compiles and can't run or is there something like no `vptr` is being created since there is no class other than abstract class present here.

```
class one {
    int a;
    public:
    one(){a=0;};
    virtual void get()=0;
};

int main() {
    one *p;
    p->get();
}
```

Comment: is there any error message or something?

Comment: There is no "`virtual ptr`" in C++. By focussing on gossip and hearsay rather than actual C++, you've missed a far more fundamental problem.

Comment: i guess there is no object so virtual pointer?? so running fails

Comment: It has nothing to do with any kind of "virtual pointer", and there really isn't even such a thing that you should need or want to know about. You have a far bigger problem with the basic notion of what a pointer is and how it can be used.

Comment: hmm, i guess i am using an incorrect term here??

Comment: @PraveenKumar: I don't know your mind, but I believe you're seriously confusing the role of classes and their layout in C++ with something completely different. Your problem would be essentially the same if it had said `int * p`.

Comment: @KerrekSB yeah yeah i got it, thanks man.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't initialise `p`, which means it's pointing to a random memory location. Dereferencing it is undefined behaviour, most likely a crash.

Comment: so i guess the compilation is successful because of the fact that it has be run time binding and at run time nothing gets returned

Comment: @PraveenKumar Just a suggestion: if you don't initialize your pointers to some "valid location", at least assign it `NULL`, `0` or `nullptr`. You would have a better chance of the runtime detecting a fault when you dereference the pointer than with any other random location.

Comment: yeah that ok, my question is why is it a successful compilation

Comment: @PraveenKumar Because it's a statically correct C++ program. It defines a pointer and dereferences it to call a member function. These are statically valid operations. The fact that `p` doesn't point anywhere is a runtime issue. Of course, if you enable compilation warnings, any decent compiler will warn you about using an uninitialised variable.

Answer (score 0):

The value of your `p` is not a valid pointer, since it's not the address of any object. Dereferencing `p` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: so i guess the compilation is successful because of the fact that it has be run time binding and at run time nothing gets returned

Comment: @PraveenKumar: It. Has. Nothing. To. Do. With. Runtime binding. Seriously, man. It's about the *basic properties of pointers*.

Comment: @PeteBecker: You're right, that's not the right term. Just "valid" should be what I'm after.